# «Женщина(,) творящая красоту»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, причастный-оборот

Как правильно написать: "женщина творящая красоту" или "женщина, творящая красоту"?
Запятая ставится однозначно или есть исключения?

Answer (score 2):

**Творящий** — это причастие (действительное, наст. вр., от глагола *творить*).
**Творящая** (что?) **красоту** — причастный оборот (причастие + существительное), который стоит после определяемого слова (женщина *какая?*).
[**Правило**](https://lampa.io/p/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82-00000000320b2387f51b662265394613): если причастный оборот стоит **после** определяемого слова, он обособляется.
Запятая ставится однозначно.

**Женщина, творящая красоту**; *Любовь, творящая красоту* (статья); *Женщины, творящие красоту* (выставка); *Якутская красота, творящая добро* (конкурс).

*Эти **язычники, творящие чудеса своим знанием и искусством,** легко могут меня умертвить* (М. Поло. Книга чудес света).

Comment: Римма, не осмелился поправить Ваш ответ. Вам не кажется, что раз последние четыре названия не предложения, а словосочетания, то лучше точек не ставить. Или я неправ?

Comment: Я сама сомневалась, когда оформляла ответ. Думаю, что возможно написать через точку с запятой. И добавить ещё один пример.

Comment: Да что такое! И я забываю иногда "?" ставить (после *Вам не кажется...*).

Answer (score 2):

Пожалуй, только одно исключение: если слова высечены на камне, то знаки пунктуации часто не ставятся.